# Checking if any substring of a string contains a combination of Alphabets and numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation

I have a textbox wherein a user is building a mathematical expression to be evaluated.

At the end his expression comes out to be as

```
4+59+8 //this is just an example.
```

however he may also type in something like

```
4+59ab+8
```

I need to detect such wrong combinations.
Can somebody provide me a suitable regex expression for it please.

Comment: Do you want to allow `alphabets` or just the `numbers`?

Comment: So you want a regexp that only allows numbers and mathematical symbols? Sounds trivial, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: No combination of alphabets and numbers are allowed( i.e 4an , 78po things like this is not allowed)

Comment: Don't worry about what's _not_ allowed, just define what _is_ allowed and check for that.

Comment: What are the correct combinations ? only Numbers or is there few letter combinations with numbers also allowed??

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression seems like what you want:

```
^[\d-+/*^]+$
```

It will allow any combination of numbers and the mathematical operators `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`, `^`.

It's not perfect, as it will allow input that's just operators, or has multiple operators in a row, etc. While it may be possible to write a regular expression that will match only the valid expressions, it would probably be better to do this in the parser that will actually evaluate the expression. Use the regexp just for simple pre-validation.

Comment: `9+*/5+` also considered as valid with this

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I know, I was updating my answer regarding that as you wrote the comment.

Comment: You can group the digits separately from the operators to make it work. Of course, once you group the digits and the operators, you no longer need to parse the rest of the regex

Comment: it gets complicated because `-` can be both an operator and the prefix for negative numbers. Not really difficult, but more work than I think it's usually worth to do in the regexp versus the parser.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex:

```
^([-+]?\d+[-+/*^])*[-+]?\d+$
```

will match a line that ends with a digit sequence, preceded by zero or more digit sequences with an operator. Is has an optional +/- prefix.

It will match:

```
95
9+5
```

but will not match:

```
95+
+95
95++5
```

With a bit more tweaking, you can even extract the numbers and the operators so you don't have to parse the expression again.

Comment: It won't allow `10*-5` or `-22+3`, i.e. negative numbers can't be used.

Comment: It does now. Just needed to add [-+]?before the digits

Answer (score 0):

You could just walk and check manually, e.g.

```
var chars = expr.ToCharArray();
var opers = new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' };
bool isOp = false;

for (var i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    char c = chars[i];

    if (opers.Contains(c))
    {
        if (isOp || i == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("operator leads or follows operator @ " + (i + 1));

        isOp = true;
    }
    else if (!char.IsNumber(c))
        throw new ArgumentException("found NaN @ " + (i + 1));
    else
        isOp = false;
}

if (isOp)
    throw new ArgumentException("ends with operator");
```